# Write the general formula for this function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

While playing with power series, I found this rather nice series from adding together series of functions.

$$\ln(1-x)+\dfrac{1}{1-x}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{2}{3}x^3+\dfrac{3}{4}x^4+\dfrac{4}{5}x^5...$$

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$ seems to be true, it looks clumsy and not handy when I do convergence tests. This series misses an $x$ term and I don't know how to express it in the formula. Is there a way to write this formula in a more succinct form, including the $1$ inside the formula?

Comment: It holds $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1},$ but the $1$ stays outside the sum.

Comment: For convergence tests, you can omit any **finite** number of coefficients. In this case, just omit the contant term of the power series.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as $$1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$ or, if you prefer $$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n}x^n$$

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to include the $1$ as well, or it is best to put it outside. The series of $\cos(x)$ also has a $1$, but it is included.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Anything can be done if you write it as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$, postulate that $x^0$ stands for the constant $1$ function and then wirte somewhere else what the sequence $a_k$ is, but I think this solution is best.

Comment: Ok thank you! I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

If $ |x|<1$, then

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}x^k$$

and by integration

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}$$

Thus

$$\ln(1-x)+\frac{1}{1-x}=$$

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(1-\frac 1k)x^k$$

Comment: Nice, I need to practice more with sigma notation.